# django - form submits information but does not save to database

Tags: python, django, database, forms, model

I've been stuck on this problem for a good bit -- the form is able to submit but will not save to the database.  I've even sent an email through the one form, but it won't save. I'm making a CRM and have a contact, communication, and email app.  This view has three forms so far, one for each model. The contact form is able to save to the DB.  The other two are able to submit but will not save.  The two forms not saving can both be redirected back to the refreshed contact detail with their instance and data still available on the form. So it must be storing properly, just not saving.  I'm not sure what I'm missing.  Let me know if you need me to add other files.

views.py----------

```
def contact_detail(request, contact_id):
    contact = get_object_or_404(Contact, pk=contact_id)

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'contact' in request.POST:
        contactForm = ContactForm(request.POST, prefix='contact', instance=contact)
        if contactForm.is_valid():
            contactForm.save()
    else:
        contactForm = ContactForm(prefix='contact', instance=contact)

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'email' in request.POST:
        contactForm = ContactForm(prefix='contact', instance=contact)
        messageForm = MessageForm(request.POST, prefix='email', instance=contact)
        if messageForm.is_valid():
            messageForm.save()
            form_email = contact.contact_email
            form_message = messageForm.cleaned_data.get("message")
            subject = messageForm.cleaned_data.get("subject")
            from_email = settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER
            to_email = [from_email]
            contact_message = "%s" % (
                form_message)
            send_mail(subject,
                      contact_message,
                      from_email,
                      to_email,
                      fail_silently=True)
    else:
        messageForm = MessageForm(prefix='email', instance=contact)

    company = Company.objects.filter(contact=contact_id)
    communications = Communication.objects.filter(contact=contact_id).order_by('-comm_date')

    if request.method == 'POST' and 'comm' in request.POST:
        contactForm = ContactForm(prefix='contact', instance=contact)
        messageForm = MessageForm(prefix='email', instance=contact)
        commForm = CommForm(request.POST, prefix='comm', instance=contact)
        if commForm.is_valid():
            commForm.save()
            redirect_url = reverse(
                'contacts:contact_detail',
                args=(contact_id,)
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect(redirect_url)

    else:
        commForm = CommForm(prefix='comm')

    context = {
        'contact': contact,
        'contactForm': contactForm,
        'company': company,
        'messageForm': messageForm,
        'communications': communications,
        'commForm': commForm}
    return render(request, 'contacts/contact_detail.html', context)
```

forms.py----------

```
from django import forms
from communications.models import Communication
from django.forms import ModelForm


class CommForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Communication
        fields = '__all__'
```

comm_form.html----------

```
<form action='' method='post'>{% csrf_token %}
    {% for field in commForm %}
      <div class='fieldWrapper'>
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }} {{ field }}
      </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <p><input type='submit' name='comm' value='submit comm' /></p>
</form>
```

models.py----------

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

from companies.models import Company
from contacts.models import Contact

class Communication(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=True, blank=True)
    contact = models.ForeignKey(Contact, null=True, blank=True)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, blank=True)
    comm = models.TextField()
    comm_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: could you put the models file for communication please?

Comment: just added the models file, thank you.  I normally wouldn't have the nulls and blanks for the foreignkey but I added them to make sure the error wasn't in correctly processing the company and contact.

Comment: It looks like the commform is missing the action?

Comment: the problem was with the instance.  I've posted the answer below.  Since I was trying to add to the database, you can't use an instance.  The instance is only used for updating to a database.  I removed the instance and it was able to save the form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out the answer and will post here in case someone comes here with a similar question.

The reason why my form was not saving to the database is because I was using an instance for the form and seeking to *add* to the db:

```
    commForm = CommForm(request.POST, prefix='comm', instance=contact)
```

If you want to *add* to the database, you can't use an instance.  An instance can only be used to *update* the database.

If you are having problems getting a form to save to the database, it might be that you are calling an instance when you simply can't yet.